# How do I start using git on my directory and pull into it updated code from pyrocms?

Tags: git, version-control, pyrocms

I  have a version of pyrocms that I want to update using git. The core files are mildly modified. I am learning git (http://git-scm.com/book). I get how to create a directory and so on, but I do not see where this is covered...

How do I start using git on my directory and pull into it updated code from pyrocms?

be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [pyrocms](http://docs.pyrocms.com/) is on a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/pyrocms/pyrocms/), it depends if you want to contribute back of just version your changes.

In both cases, doing a **[fork](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo)** of that repo on GitHub is the safest way to:

- have your own local clone you can modify
- keep said local clone updated from the original repo
- do, if you want, **[pull requests](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests)** in order to contribute to the original project.

[image: fork]

So:

- fork the repo on GitHub
- clone your fork
- modify your file and push back to origin
- pull from time to time from "upstream" repo (the original pyrocms repo), to kept your local repo up-to-date.

Comment: you show modifying a clone. I already have a modified copy of pyrocms that was not from a clone or fork. I had downloaded the code and began using it. NOW, I want to update it via git.

Comment: @Robert you should fork and clone, then report your modifications in that local clone. Easier that way.

Comment: Okay, so I have done this... then went back and migrated the _mild_ changes from my previous install. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Continue to read book: [Git Basics - Working with Remotes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes)